# how can we unpublish item with its subitem for one particular language in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, publishing

we have option in ribbon publish - > change but that is not unpublishing subitems .

how can we unpublish item with its subitem for one particular language in sitecore ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1:**
In the Publish ribbon, click the Change button and UNCHECK Publishable on the Item tab. Now delete the parent item with sub-items and the item will be removed from the published DB. Next go back to the item and CHECK Publishable, then publish the item only in the language you want.

**Approach 2:**
Use the database selector in the Sitecore shell (bottom right corner) and select your publishing target DB (e.g. "web"). GO into that tree, find the item in the language and delete that version. After that you'll need to go to your public site's cache page and clear that cache manually: `http://host/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`

**Approach 3:**
Delete the item in the master DB, publish the parent, restore it form the recycle bin, publish it again live but not in the language you don't want.

Comment: but say in case I dont want to delete version and want to just unpubsih it for one particular language with subitem ..is it possible ?

Comment: issue is how to unpublish item with subitem in sitecore without deleting it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You cannot unpublish just a specific language version unless you follow the approach above.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark . So this means once published for more than one language without deleting unwanted language you CAN NOT remove that language from web DB unless you delete it ??

Comment: Well if you follow Approach 2 you are deleting it from the published DB. Eg web

Comment: yes but even though its web DB we are manually deleting it . I was thinking if we can have approach where we can just unpublish it without deleting it from any of the DB . unpublishing will eventually delete item from web db but looking for a option where you can handle everything from master db without deleting item and just unpublish it from web db . I even tried option  "never publish" in publishing section (ofcourse after unsharing it ) but that is also unpublishing entire site instead of just that language .

Comment: Yes you can absolutely do this out of the box! Use approach 1 above and publish the parent item, which will remove the items from the web database, effectively deleting them. This by far the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

some script is also fine :)
just publish site after use it

```
 function GetItemDatasources {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Item]$Item)
  
    # grab all datasources that are not header and footer elements
    return Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout -Device (Get-LayoutDevice -Default) |
        Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Datasource)} |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Above Page Content' } |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Below Page Content' } |
        ForEach-Object { Get-Item "$($item.Database):" -ID $_.Datasource }
        # ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_ | Format-List | Out-String) }
}
  
$location = get-location
  
$languages = Get-ChildItem "master:\sitecore\system\Languages"
$currentLanguage = [Sitecore.Context]::Language.Name
  
$langOptions = @{};
  
foreach ($lang in $languages) {
    $langOptions[$lang.Name] = $lang.Name
}
  

$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "destinationLanguages"; Title="Language(s) for clean up "; Options=$langOptions; Editor="checklist"; },
    @{ Name = "includeSubitems"; Value=$false; Title="Include Subitems"; Columns = 4;} `
    -Description "Select an  languages that should be cleanup" `
    -Title "Cleanup Language" -Width 650 -Height 660 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Cancel" -ShowHints
  
if($result -ne "ok") {
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "destinationLanguages = $destinationLanguages"
  
$items = @()
  
$items += Get-Item $location
  
# add optional subitems
if ($includeSubitems) {
    $items += Get-ChildItem $location -Recurse
}
  
# Remove any duplicates, based on ID
$items = $items | Sort-Object -Property 'ID' -Unique
  
$items | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_.ItemPath | Sort-Object | Format-List | Out-String) }
  
$message = "You are about to cleanup <span style='font-weight: bold'>$($items.Count) item(s)</span> with the following options:<br>"
$message += "<br><table>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Languages:</td><td>$destinationLanguages</td></tr>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Include Subitems:</td><td>$includeSubitems</td></tr>"
$message += "</table>"
$message += "<br><p style='font-weight: bold'>Are you sure?</p>"
  
  
$proceed = Show-Confirm -Title $message
  
if ($proceed -ne 'yes') {
    Write-Host "Canceling"
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "Proceeding with execution"
  
$items | ForEach-Object { Remove-ItemVersion -Item $_ -Language $destinationLanguages -ExcludeLanguage "en*" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
  function GetItemDatasources {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Item]$Item)
  
    # grab all datasources that are not header and footer elements
    return Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout -Device (Get-LayoutDevice -Default) |
        Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Datasource)} |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Above Page Content' } |
        Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -ne 'Below Page Content' } |
        ForEach-Object { Get-Item "$($item.Database):" -ID $_.Datasource }
        # ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_ | Format-List | Out-String) }
}
  
$location = get-location
  
$languages = Get-ChildItem "master:\sitecore\system\Languages"
$currentLanguage = [Sitecore.Context]::Language.Name
  
$langOptions = @{};
  
$actions = @{};
$actions["Unpublish"] = "1";
$actions["Publish"] = "";
  
foreach ($lang in $languages) {
    $langOptions[$lang.Name] = $lang.Name
}
  
$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "destinationLanguages"; Title="Language(s) for publich/unpublish"; Options=$langOptions; Editor="checklist"; },
    @{ Name = "includeSubitems"; Value=$false; Title="Include Subitems"; Columns = 4;},
    @{ Name = "action"; Value="1"; Title="Action"; Options=$actions; Tooltip="Unpublish: Set language as unblishded on all langauge vestions.<br>Publish: Set language as publishded on all langauge vestions."; }`
    -Description "Select languages that should be proceed during updates" `
    -Title "Language Publish - Unpublish" -Width 650 -Height 660 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Cancel" -ShowHints
  
if($result -ne "ok") {
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "destinationLanguages = $destinationLanguages"
  
$items = @()
  
$items += Get-Item $location
  
# add optional subitems
if ($includeSubitems) {
    $items += Get-ChildItem $location -Recurse
}
  
# Remove any duplicates, based on ID
$items = $items | Sort-Object -Property 'ID' -Unique
  
$items | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ($_.ItemPath | Sort-Object | Format-List | Out-String) }
  
$message = "You are about to publish/unpublish <span style='font-weight: bold'>$($items.Count) item(s)</span> with the following options:<br>"
$message += "<br><table>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Languages:</td><td>$destinationLanguages</td></tr>"
$message += "<tr><td style='width: auto'>Include Subitems:</td><td>$includeSubitems</td></tr>"
$message += "</table>"
$message += "<br><p style='font-weight: bold'>Are you sure?</p>"
  
$proceed = Show-Confirm -Title $message
  
if ($proceed -ne 'yes') {
    Write-Host "Canceling"
    Exit
}
  
Write-Host "Proceeding with execution"
  
$items | ForEach-Object { 
    $vitems = Get-Item $_.ID -Language $destinationLanguages -Version *
    $vitems | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $_["__Hide version"] = $action
        $_.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}
```